# how to select all rows from a DataTable

Tags: c#, foreach, datarow

I can't seem to figure out how to just return all rows when using Select on a DataTable.

My code so far:

```
foreach (DataRow r in data.Select("Sort != null", "Sort"))
{ //process }
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot interpret token '!'

The ***Sort*** column is of type *Guid* and is used to return the rows in a random order.

Comment: Have you tried  "Sort IS NOT NULL" ?

Comment: Go Through This Link ---
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead...

```
foreach (DataRow r in data.Select("Sort IS NOT NULL", "Sort"))
{ //process }
```

Comment: Thanks for re-posting my comment as the answer.

Comment: @pmcilreavy — How do you know he did that? The answer is already known to many people; he could have been simply applying his own knowledge. Best to offer the benefit of the doubt, I think, before accusing. Saves from false accusations. (That said, it's possible I misunderstood your comment and falsely accused you ;-)

Comment: Oops, my bad -- I didn't see your comment.  I'm slightly embarrassed now.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
foreach (DataRow r in data.Select("Sort <> null", "Sort"))
{ //process }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
foreach (DataRow r in data.Select())
{ //process }
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netframework-4.8